# How to reset onClick listeners after a transition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-transitions

I have created a transition manager in resources and run a transition when one of the buttons on my main layout is clicked. The idea is very simple: run transition inflated from resources and transition to scene_login when the login button is clicked, and run the same transition when the signup button is clicked and transition to scene_signup. 
When the back button is clicked, undo the transitions smoothly, and be ready for click events on the buttons again.
A Boolean variable is used to keep track of whether the a transition is started. 
After a transition run, the buttons do not receive the onClick events anymore. This means that I cannot run subsequent transitions, which will run inside `onClick()`. Never encountered this before. Any idea?

R.transition.transition_mgr:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionManager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <transition android:transition="@transition/mytransitions"  android:toScene="@layout/scene_signup"/>
  <transition android:transition="@transition/mytransitions" android:toScene="@layout/scene_login"/>
  <transition android:transition="@transition/mytransitions" android:toScene="@layout/activity_main"/>
</transitionManager>
```

R.transition.mytransitions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<transitionSet android:duration="3000"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <changeBounds/>
    <fade/>
</transitionSet>
```

R.layout.activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Log In"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".5" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

R.layout.scene_login:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Log In"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

R.layout.scene_signup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/confirmPassword"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password (again)"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Phone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/confirmPassword" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    Button signupButton;
    Button loginButton;
    boolean transitionStarted = false;
    TransitionManager transitionMgr;
    Scene scene_main;
    Scene scene_login;
    Scene scene_signup;
    ViewGroup root;
    Context mContext = this;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        signupButton = findViewById(R.id.signup);
        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login);


        root = findViewById(R.id.root);
        transitionMgr = TransitionInflater.from(mContext).inflateTransitionManager(R.transition.transition_mgr, root);
        scene_main = Scene.getSceneForLayout(root, R.layout.activity_main, mContext);
        scene_login = Scene.getSceneForLayout(root, R.layout.scene_login, mContext);
        scene_signup = Scene.getSceneForLayout(root, R.layout.scene_signup, mContext);

        signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: transitionStarted: " + transitionStarted );

                if(!transitionStarted) {
                    transitionMgr.transitionTo(scene_signup);
                    transitionStarted = true;
                }
            }
        });
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: transitionStarted: " + transitionStarted);

                if(!transitionStarted) {
                    transitionMgr.transitionTo(scene_login);
                    transitionStarted = true;
                }
            }
        });





    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBackPressed: transitionStarted: " + transitionStarted);
        if(transitionStarted) {
            transitionStarted = false;
            transitionMgr.transitionTo(scene_main);
        }
        else
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

PS. It seems that by transitioning to a new scene, information of views including any onClick listeners is cleared, and we probably need to find the views again and set required listeners.

Comment: that is a whole bunch of code.

Comment: Sorry @DroiDev let me add some explanation.

Comment: what is the transition you are doing? fading?

Comment: @DroiDev fade and changeBounds. The problem is that after the first transition, the click events are not triggered anymore.

Comment: main activity to login.... then when u go back to the main activity, the onclick doesnt work again? im never done this, but the logic tells me that you need to reset the on click to true on onResume

Comment: @DroiDev, note that I don't leave main activity. I just load scenes and transition across them. Do I still need to call onResume and do stuff there?

Comment: https://medium.com/@andkulikov/animate-all-the-things-transitions-in-android-914af5477d50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that after transitioning to a new scene, view info like onClick listeners are cleared since view hierarchy changes, despite the fact that you might create views in different with the same IDs.
To keep onClick working after transition, you need to find respective views again and reset onClick listeners on them.

Revised activity code (working) (Also on [GitHub](https://github.com/djnotes/KitkatTransitions)):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        when(p0?.id) {
            R.id.register -> {
                if (!animationStarted) {
                    TransitionManager.go(sceneRegister, set);
                    animationStarted = true;
                }
            }
            R.id.login -> {
                if(!animationStarted) {
                    TransitionManager.go(sceneLogin, set);
                    animationStarted = true;
                }
            }

        }

    }


    var animationStarted = false;

    lateinit var scene: Scene
    lateinit var login: Button
    lateinit var register: Button
    lateinit var root : ViewGroup
    lateinit var sceneRegister: Scene
    lateinit var sceneLogin: Scene
    lateinit var set: TransitionSet


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        login = findViewById<Button>(R.id.login);
        register = findViewById<Button>(R.id.register);
        root = findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.id.root);
        scene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(root, R.layout.main_activity, this);
        sceneLogin = Scene.getSceneForLayout(root, R.layout.main_activity_login, this);
        sceneRegister = Scene.getSceneForLayout(root, R.layout.main_activity_register, this);

        set = TransitionSet();

        set.addTransition(ChangeBounds()).addTransition(Fade()).addTransition(AutoTransition());

        login.setOnClickListener (this)
        register.setOnClickListener(this)




    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if(animationStarted) {
            val root = findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.id.root);
            TransitionManager.go(scene, ChangeBounds() );
            animationStarted = false;
            login = findViewById(R.id.login)
            register = findViewById(R.id.register)

            login.setOnClickListener(this)
            register.setOnClickListener(this)
        }
        else {

            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
}
```